# AWTUtilities not found

Tags: java, java-6, translucency, awtutilities

I am working on a small Java application and I'd like to use transparent windows. However when I use `AWTUtilities.<any method>` I get this:

> 'AWTUtilities cannot be resolved'

I've looked for solutions but I'm unable to understand them. Could you please explain to me in simpler terms how I can deal with this? I'm on Java Version 6u23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this paper](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) it mentions that you should use this class using reflection since it's not part of the official Java API. Look in the middle of the paper.

Comment: I went thru it. I'm sorry but it didn't really help me. What should I do?

Comment: Figure out how to use Java Reflection to call the methods on the AWTUtilities class. Java Reflection is a way that you can call methods dynamically (without having the compiler be involved).

Answer (score 0):

AWTUtilities is a "undocumented" API put into java around version 6.12, hence the reason you are suggested to use reflection, this allows you application to run on JVMs that don't support it yet